# Error using PHPUnit 3.7.7 and Symfony2

Tags: symfony, phpunit, runtime-error, symfony-2.1

Brand new install of both PHPUnit 3.7.7 and Symfony2.1.2.  When I try running PHPUnit on the Acme bundle that comes pre-installed as a demo, I get the following error:

```
$ phpunit -c app/
PHPUnit 3.7.7 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /home/kevin/www/diva/app/phpunit.xml.dist

E

Time: 4 seconds, Memory: 7.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\Controller\DemoControllerTest::testIndex
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "enable" under "framework.profiler"

/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/ArrayNode.php:278
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/BaseNode.php:266
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/ArrayNode.php:270
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/BaseNode.php:266
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Processor.php:35
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Processor.php:52
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/Extension.php:103
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php:62
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:42
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:39
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php:119
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:453
/home/kevin/www/diva/app/bootstrap.php.cache:945
/home/kevin/www/diva/app/bootstrap.php.cache:854
/home/kevin/www/diva/app/bootstrap.php.cache:566
/home/kevin/www/diva/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/WebTestCase.php:43
/home/kevin/www/diva/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Tests/Controller/DemoControllerTest.php:11

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `framework.profiler` from `app/config/config_test.yml` removes the error, but seems like a sloppy hack that doesn't address the underlying problem.

EDIT: According to the official forums, its inclusion in the 2.1.2 standard edition may be a mistake: http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=49451